# coldfusion cfcontent want to offer open file but not download

Tags: file-io, coldfusion

In ColdFusion I have code to open or download a file:

```
<cfif FileExists('#session.exploc#/#attname#')>      
  <cfset typeatt =  FilegetMimeType('#session.exploc#/#attname#')>      
  <cfheader name = "Content-Disposition" value="attachment;#session.exploc#/#attname#"> 
  <cfcontent type="#typeatt#" file="#session.exploc#/#attname#">
</cfif>
```

This gives a standard open/download window.

I would prefer a window which just allows the user to open the file, and does not provide a download.  Is there a way to do that?

Alternatively, I am happy to open the file in the browser, but since I don't know the filetype in advance I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a function of `<cfcontent>` per-se. All `<cfcontent>` handles is the MIME-type of the response, the content of it (it can reset it for example), and a few other bits and pieces. It's all about the nature of the content returned by the CFML server.

This is all fairly clear in the docs for [`<cfcontent>`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-c/cfcontent.html):

> Some file types, such as PDF documents, do not use executable code and can display directly in most browsers. To request the browser to display the file directly, use a cfheader tag similar to the following:

```
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=name.ext">
```

IE: what you want to be doing is to set the [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) *header* with a value of `inline` to tell the *browser* to potentially inline the document, if if has the capabilities to do so.

Comment: Yes, changing the header to inline worked for a .jpg and I presume will work for a .pdf.  When I used a .doc I got the window to open or download.  All this is good. But I would prefer the window  does not offer a download option.  Can this be done?

Comment: No. Server side languages don't control that behavior, client browser settings do. If a browser has been configured to open a file inline, it will do so. Otherwise, it will display the prompt.

Comment: correction: configured to open a file *type*

Comment: Yeah, as SOS alludes to... this is standard browser behaviour and my wording was deliberate: "to tell the browser to potentially inline the document, if if has the capabilities to do so.". IF IT HAS THE CAPABILITIES TO DO SO. It's not magic. If the browser doesn't know what to do with a .doc file, all it can do is go "here, download it and you do something with it"